# OleDbException syntax error in INSERT INTO statement

Tags: sql, ms-access, oledb, oledbcommand, reserved-words

I'm building an SQL INSERT command using the OleDbCommandBuilder

```
adapter.InsertCommand = builder.GetInsertCommand();
```

and I get an exception while trying to add data to database on this line:

```
adapter.Update(ds, tableName);
```

and the exception:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Syntax error in INSERT INTO
>   statement.'

I've set a breakpoint on this line and found out that the syntax of the insert command is correct:

```
INSERT INTO order (orderid, employeeid, dateestimated, datearrived) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

And the parameters are correct as well: 0x1, 0x2, 13/10/2017, null

Why am I getting a syntax error exception when the syntax is clearly correct and the parameters are right?

The exception's source says Microsoft Access Database Engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have called your table `order`. This is the reserved MS-Access/SQL keyword. Try renaming your table to `orders` or some other name. Or try adding `[...]` making it to be `[order]` if you have control over the generated SQL statement.

You can find the full list of MS-Access reserved keywords here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-E33EB3A9-8BAA-4335-9F57-DA237C63EABE

The general rule is to try to avoid naming tables/columns using any of these words. However, if you absolutely need you can use `[` and `]` symbols around column name to escape it.

Comment: It seems like the right answer, applying the fix now

Comment: @Keddy1201, glad it helped. Would appreciate answer accept/vote-up, thanks.

Comment: done, this was the correct answer and was driving me crazy for hours. hopefully this answer will also help others .